# EAV Model - how to handle internationalization

Tags: java, spring, entity-attribute-value

I have an existing spring mvc application with hibernate and mysql.
 I have requirement to create dynamic form in this application and i am planning to use EAV model.

How can i handle internationalization?

currently i have the messages_en.properties file inside WebContent/resources folder and the configuration is

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
   <property name="basename" value="/resources/messages" /> 
   <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" /> 
</bean>
```

For dynamic form when i create a text field how should i add the label to the properties file?

I hope this question is written well enough to SO standards. if you need any additional information, please do not hesitate to ask and I will try to help you help me. :)

Comment: The label would be part of the attribute so store it there (e.g. in a map language->label).

Comment: Thank you Thomas.But later if any other language need to be supported that also need to be stored in database?

Comment: If you need to be able to add new attributes at runtime that's probably the best option. If not (you only operate on existing attributes) then you can also just store some resource key in the attribute and use that to look up the label in the resource bundle

Comment: Thanks again.I am sorry i am not so clear on this above comment.Do we need to write the value to the properties file manually after dynamic from creation?

Comment: I'd not write any value to any properties file at runtime. If the attribute is created at runtime you should store its label in the database. If the label for the attribute should be different on the form then you also need to store that in the database just not on the attribute but the attribute-form relation (you might need to create a new entity for that).